# How to handle error upon clicking WorkAccount when domain is not federated with Azure

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

We are using Custom SignUpSignIn policy in which we give the user option of Social IDP's, WorkAccount and LocalSignUp/SignIn.

When a user clicks on workaccount, it takes the user to Microsoft page(https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?). And when user enters the email address, if that domain is not federated, it is taking to an error page.

How can we notify user instead of showing error page, is it possible?

Thanks,

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what you mean by "domain is not federated"?

Comment: I meant if that corp client account not connected to office 365, but tried to login using their workaccount option

Comment: Do you mean the "We couldn't find an account with that username. Try another, or get a new Microsoft account." error?

Comment: Yes, if we can show any page than error page is good

Comment: any thoughts please

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, by redirecting the external authentication to Azure AD, you can't control the error handling.